# Group by where category having max value

Tags: hadoop, hive, data-science, hiveql

Here is my `t`table

```
 +---------------+------------------------------+---------------+--+                                                                                          
    | trading_year  |            sector            | total_volume  |                                                                                             
    +---------------+------------------------------+---------------+--+                                                                                          
    | 2010          | Consumer Discretionary       | 119621915300  |                                                                                             
    | 2012          | Consumer Discretionary       | 93805031400   |                                                                                             
    | 2014          | Consumer Discretionary       | 80018436200   |                                                                                             
    | 2016          | Consumer Discretionary       | 81834656900   |                                                                                             
    | 2010          | Consumer Staples             | 50710518800   |                                                                                             
    | 2012          | Consumer Staples             | 39340784200   |                                                                                             
    | 2014          | Consumer Staples             | 33188087300   |                                                                                             
    | 2016          | Consumer Staples             | 37538472900   |
```

i need to label the above data based on the max and min value of total_volume grouped by the sector

so my output should be  like this

```
 +---------------+------------------------------+---------------+----------------+                                                                                          
    | trading_year  |            sector            | total_volume  |     value                                                                                        
    +---------------+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+                                                                                          
    | 2010          | Consumer Discretionary       | 119621915300  |   maxvalue                                                                                            
    | 2012          | Consumer Discretionary       | 93805031400   |   stable value                                                                                         
    | 2014          | Consumer Discretionary       | 80018436200   |   stable value                                                                                          
    | 2016          | Consumer Discretionary       | 81834656900   |   minvalue                                                                                          
    | 2010          | Consumer Staples             | 50710518800   |   maxvalue                                                                                          
    | 2012          | Consumer Staples             | 39340784200   |   stable value                                                                                          
    | 2014          | Consumer Staples             | 33188087300   |   minvalue                                                                                          
    | 2016          | Consumer Staples             | 37538472900   |   stable value
```

here is my query i tried but no luck

```
select *,
case when total_volume = max(total_volume) then 'maxvalue'
     when total_volume = min(total_volume) then 'minvalue'
     else 'stable value'
end value_type
from t
group by sector,trading_year
```

output from above query

```
+---------------+------------------------------+---------------+----------------+                                                                                          
    | trading_year  |            sector            | total_volume  |     value                                                                                        
    +---------------+------------------------------+---------------+--------------+                                                                                          
    | 2010          | Consumer Discretionary       | 119621915300  |   maxvalue                                                                                            
    | 2012          | Consumer Discretionary       | 93805031400   |   maxvalue                                                                                         
    | 2014          | Consumer Discretionary       | 80018436200   |   maxvalue                                                                                          
    | 2016          | Consumer Discretionary       | 81834656900   |   maxvalue                                                                                       
    | 2010          | Consumer Staples             | 50710518800   |   maxvalue                                                                                          
    | 2012          | Consumer Staples             | 39340784200   |   maxvalue                                                                                         
    | 2014          | Consumer Staples             | 33188087300   |   maxvalue                                                                                         
    | 2016          | Consumer Staples             | 37538472900   |   maxvalue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL won't work here. Don't use `group by` since you wanna preserve all the rows. What we need for this is **windowing and analytics**.

```sql
select 
    t.*, 
    case 
        when total_volume = last_value(total_volume)  over w then 'maxvalue'
        when total_volume = first_value(total_volume) over w then 'minvalue'
        else 'stable value'
    end as value 
from t
window w as (partition by sector order by total_volume 
    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```

Have a nice day :)

**UPDATE:**
Yet another (simpler) way:

```sql
select 
    t.*, 
    case 
        when total_volume = max(total_volume) over w then 'maxvalue'
        when total_volume = min(total_volume) over w then 'minvalue'
        else 'stable value'
    end as value 
from t
window w as (partition by sector)
```

Note, without `order by`, the default window specification is `rows between unbounded proceeding and unbounded following`. Whereas with `order by`, the window specification is defaulted to `rows between unbounded proceeding and current row`.